# Separate the sentence and the years(numbers) in php

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a string like "The beer party 2011/2012" in PHP.

I still cannot figure how to make these years and the sentence into two different arrays? Like this:

```
$arr[0] = the beer party;
$arr[1] = 2011/2012 or if its just 2011 then $arr[1] = 2011;
```

I have tried `\d+` and `\S+\s+` but do not know how to use it with combined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match('/(.*?)\s?(\d{4}(?:\/\d{4})*)$/', $yourString, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` contains the sentence `$matches[2]` contains the date.

Comment: Maybe could be simplified a bit, but it workwwell and robust.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the regex "(.*?)([\d\/]+)", or similar.

Breaking it apart is:

(.*?) - first capture group, any character in an *ungreedy* way.
[\d\/] - either a number or the literal "/" (slash). This is to capture things like 2011*/*2012.
([\d\/]+) - the second capture group captures the previous statement.

If the first capture group was greedy, it could capture the number literals as well. Since it is ungreedy, it will stop to allow the longest greedy capturer, which is the second capture group.

For more information about greediness in regex, you can look into http://www.skdevelopment.com/php-regular-expressions.php.

Hope this helps!

Comment: There's an error in your regex; you need to escape the literal slash you are trying to match (or use different delimiters). Also your match breaks on strings like "The beer party/2 2011/2012"

Comment: Correct! I actually did escape it. I think it was removed somehow in the textile. Regarding the second part, it seemed from the question that these instances do not occur..

Comment: thank you so much i will need to study regex more, thing is just looks so complicated

Answer (score 0):

If your target strings are always in that format (i.e. ending in one or more 4-digit years separated by slashes) then you can use this

```
preg_match( '/(\d{4}(\/\d{4})*)$/', $string, $matches );
```

This will match any strings of the format "YYYY" or "YYYY/YYYY" in your string which you can then remove to get the two parts.